# PostgreSQL: Deleting records to keep the one with the latest timestamps

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Let's say I have a table with a column of timestamps and a column of IDs (numeric). For each ID, I'm trying to delete all the rows except the one with the latest timestamp.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
DELETE FROM table_name t1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name t2
WHERE t2."ID" = t1."ID"
AND t2."LOCAL_DATETIME_DTE" > t1."LOCAL_DATETIME_DTE")
```

This code seems to work, but my question is: why is it a `>` sign and not a `<` sign in the timestamp comparison? Is this not selecting for deletion all the rows with a later timestamp than another row? I thought this code would keep only the rows with the earliest timestamps for each ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `EXISTS` operator to delete records for which a record can be found with a larger, thus `>`, timestamp. For the newest, there isn't a record with a higher timestamp, so the `WHERE` clause doesn't resolve to `true` and therefore the record is kept.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "record" pseudo-type to match tuples:

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE (ID,LOCAL_DATETIME_DTE) not in 
(SELECT ID,max(LOCAL_DATETIME_DTE) FROM table_name group by id);
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternate way of doing things!